# OCI RestAPI to list VNIC Attachement to a compute instance

Tags: oracle-cloud-infrastructure

On Oracle cloud infrastructure, I am trying to get the details of the VNICs attached to a compute instance. I can see there is an option available in oci-cli to pass the OCID of a compute instance and it provides the details of VNICs attached to the instance (works well !!).

```
oci compute instance list-vnics --instance-id <OCID of compute instance>
```

Reference: https://docs.cloud.oracle.com/iaas/tools/oci-cli/latest/oci_cli_docs/cmdref/compute/instance/list-vnics.html

However, there is no option available to get the same when REST API are used:
https://docs.cloud.oracle.com/iaas/api/#/en/iaas/20160918/Instance/

Please suggest the equivalent Rest API to retrieve the same result ?

The ultimate goal is to get the public IP of a OCI compute instance using RestAPI.

Answer (score 2):

You'll want to use the [ListVnicAttachments API](https://docs.cloud.oracle.com/iaas/api/#/en/iaas/20160918/VnicAttachment/ListVnicAttachments), filtering on a specific instanceId, and then for each VnicAttachment response object call the [GetVnic API](https://docs.cloud.oracle.com/iaas/api/#/en/iaas/20160918/Vnic/GetVnic), passing in the vnicId of the VnicAttachment.

Comment: Thanks Joe ! Before posting the thread, I too got the same flow to get VnicAttachment then pass the vnicId to get the details. but as you see its two step process however in oci-cli, the results are obtained in one step. So, want to find out is there any other way to obtain the same results in less number of steps.

The ultimate goal is to get the public IP of a compute instance using RestAPI.

Comment: The CLI internally does the above, so while it appears as one step to the end user, its actually still multiple API calls behind the scenes. Unfortunately there isn't a one-step way to do this at the moment.